# Merge based on common values

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to merge column based on common values and return NAN if there is no match. I tried below code but the output is wierd. Even though there is no match, the values are returning

```
import pandas as pd

data2 = {'Name' : ['Tom', 'Nick', 'f']}
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data1 = {'Name' : ['Tom', 'Nick', 'h', 'g']}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

(d1 on d2)

```
pd.merge(d2, d1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left') 

  Name_x Name_y
0    Tom    Tom
1   Nick   Nick
2      f      h
```

But expected output (d1 on d2)

```
  Name_x Name_y
0    Tom    Tom
1   Nick   Nick
2      f      NaN
```

Similarly(d2 on d1)

```
pd.merge(d1, d2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
Out[17]: 
  Name_x Name_y
0    Tom    Tom
1   Nick   Nick
2      h      f
3      g    NaN
```

Expected output (d2 on d1)

```
  Name_x Name_y
0    Tom    Tom
1   Nick   Nick
2      h    NaN
3      g    NaN
```

So basically, it should compare the 2 dataframe and depending on mismatch values, it should return NaN

Comment: the easy way out would just keep what you have but then compare Name_x and Name_y after the fact and if they don't match then replace with NaN

Comment: Have you tried merging on `Name` instead of `Index`?

Answer (score 0):

See the comment on your post, but you could do this of just comparing after the fact and replacing with NaN if they don't match.

```
df = pd.merge(d1, d2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
print(len(df))
for x in range(len(df)):
    if df['Name_x'][x] != df['Name_y'][x]:
        df['Name_y'][x] = np.NaN

print(df)
```

```
  Name_x Name_y
0    Tom    Tom
1   Nick   Nick
2      h    NaN
3      g    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the way you invoked it will use the index. Your data frames have index as a numeric range (the default). You need to set Name to be the index (or invoke merge differently).

```
import pandas as pd
 
data2 = {'Name' : ['Tom', 'Nick', 'f']}
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
d2.set_index('Name',drop=False,inplace=True)
                                             
data1 = {'Name' : ['Tom', 'Nick', 'h', 'g']}
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
d1.set_index('Name',drop=False,inplace=True)
                                              
print(pd.merge(d2, d1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left'))
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `indicator` param and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) clause (to reassign values basing on merge markers):

```
df_ = d1.merge(d2, how='left', indicator='Name_y').rename({'Name': 'Name_x'}, axis=1)
df_['Name_y'] = np.where(df_['Name_y'].eq('both'), df_['Name_x'], pd.NA)
print(df_)
```

---

```
  Name_x Name_y
0    Tom    Tom
1   Nick   Nick
2      h   <NA>
3      g   <NA>
```